# I keep having an error whenever I run my Visual Basic code

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors, handle, basic

I keep having an error in my Visual Basic console, error BC30506:

> Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1_Click.Click 

        Dim score As Double
        score = txtScore.Text
        Select case score 
            case 70 to 100
                txtletter.Text = "A"
            case 60 to 69
                txtletter.Text = "B"
            case 50 to 59
                txtletter.Text = "C"
            case 45 to 49
                txtletter.Text = "D"
            case 40 to 44
                txtletter.Text = "E"
            case 0 to 39
                txtletter.Text = "F"
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `... Handles Button1.Click` ?

Comment: same error, sigh*

Comment: Is it a WinForm app? If so, switch to the designer, select that button and double click on it to add the default `Click` event handler. If you get different handler, use it instead of current one. Also, what's the `Name` of the button? `Button1_Click` or just `Button1`? Get that from the Properties window.

Comment: Side note: You should [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement).

Comment: You definitely don't have a control named `Button1_Click` so why do you have `Handles Button1_Click.Click` at the end of the method? If you have a control named `Button1` then if you actually do as you were told then it would work. If you don't have a control named `Button1` then why are you trying to handle a `Click` event of such a control in the first place? Just add a `Button` with that name to your form.